# How can I dyamically load multiple scripts by order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm lazy loading various scripts depending on what page I'm on. Up till now, I've only loaded one per page. Now that I'm starting to clean up and reduce the number of scripts, I have to lazy load two scripts (or more) scripts for the same page. One script is dependent of the other so I need to load these in correct order.

What is the best way to achieve this?

My code:

```
// Plupload must load before imageHandling.js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Conditional load
    load_script('.image-drop-box','vendor/plupload/plupload.full.min.js');
    load_script('.image-drop-box','imageHandling.js');

});


// Script loader
// .exists() is a custom func that checks if an element exists on page
function load_script(element, js) {
    $(element).exists(function(){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = '/js/'+ js;
        footer.appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

Comment: what's the actual problem with the given code? Nothing has loaded? The loading order is wrong? The browser raises an error? what is the body of `exists` function?

Comment: See there for good sync example:http://trevweb.me.uk/javascripthtml-synchronous-and-asynchronous-loading/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not stepping out of the same domain, you could use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
var scriptUrls = ["http://x/foo", "http://x/bar"];
var loadScr;
loadScr = function(){
    if(scriptUrls.length==0)return;
    var currentUrl = scriptUrls.pop();
    $.getScript(url, loadScr);
}
loadScr();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm adding the script links to my footer to ensure quicker page load. Not sure how effective it is though.

Comment: `.getScript ()` is async by default

Comment: @A.Wolff so if it is async, wouldn't that mean that order may not be preserved?

Comment: @Adjit you cannot be sure than first one is loaded in first especially if both come from different domains

Answer (score 3):

there is a jquery plugin with callback. you could use that, the call back function will be triggered after loading the first script, this plugin uses lazyloading system
[jquery loadscript plugin](http://marcbuils.github.io/jquery.loadscript/)
usage

```
$.loadScript( url [, callback()] )
```

or

```
var s= ["http://firstLink", "http://secondLink"];
function get_script(){
    if(scripts.length==0)
        return;
    var x = s.pop();
    $.ajax({
      url: x,
      dataType: "script",
      async:true,
      success: function(){
        get_script();
      },
      error: function(){
            //console.log( x+ 'failed' );
      }
    });
}
get_script();
```

even though second one looks lengthy, i prefer that.(just a personal opinion, correct me if there is a better option)

Comment: How would you implement this to load multiple scripts? function and variable?

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks i will correct that. adjit, actually the ajax call is in a function i expanded it for readability

Comment: my bad havent noticed that

Comment: I like the ajax call, the only thing is if you want to import 10 wouldn't that make it a fairly lengthy function? Would you be able to have a recursive success call that will load the next script in an array?

Comment: Forget about async false because you are using relevant callback, my bad!

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it only loads one script out of two in the array. @spender's script worked however.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to ensure that the scripts are loaded in correct order even if they are writted in wrong order? Maybe you should give your function the objects as array and check it in a "while" loop to ensure that no one is loaded until his "previous requeriments" have been loaded. But you need or write and read this requeriments from .js or make a list with requeriments.